ROBDDs heuristics for optimal variable ordering
I have this slide about how a BDD can vary in size depending on the order of the boolean variables fixed for it, and how it is NP-Complete to find the optimal ordering.

It says there are heuristics to find good orderings but I haven't been able to find any, so I wanted to ask what they are.

You can check the documentation of the CUDD BDD library, which implements several of them.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram#Variable_ordering, http://alumni.cs.ucr.edu/~skulhari/StaticHeuristics.pdf
